# Emacs org-mode agenda filter doesn't work. :(

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have exactly this org file:

```
* TODO EAT                                 :home:
** make 
** me
** a
** sandwich
* TODO CODE                                :home:
** make
** me
** code
* TODO SLEEP                                :bed:
** dream with
** dragons
* TODO REPEAT                              :universe:
```

I want to filter it by tags, so I:

1. `M-x + org-agenda`
2. `m`
3. `home`

Then nothing. As if there wasn't any item tagged with home. Although, as you can see, there is.

I'm I doing something wrong?
I can not filter by anything, even the "All TODO's" option displays no items at all.

I really want to get into org-mode. Please help me :(

Comment: Should ask in http://emacs.stackexchange.com/, but the problem is likely that you need to put your .org file in the default directory that org-agenda will look in, or you need to re-configure that directory.

Comment: And what for emacs and org-mode tags exists here? (I'm not being ironic, it's a serious question) @NateW.

Comment: That emacs-specific site hasn't always existed, so emacs questions used to be asked here.  The tags are free-form, so they exist as soon as someone tags their post as such.  Didn't mean to sound short there, apologies if I did :)

Comment: No problem. :) How can I know in which directory org-agenda will look for? Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what's broken for you, you could start looking at the documentation for `org-agenda-files`.  
I have mine set like `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/todo.org" "~/org/capture.org"))` which might actually be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

To add my document to org-agenda:

```
M-x + [
```

Then it works like a charm. :)